# Implement function array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have a code for a loto which allows us to find and compare number in a array using loops.I need to update my program so that the work of checking the result is done
by a function called checkNumber. This function should take the customer
number and the array of winning numbers as arguments. The customer number
should be returned from a function called getCustomerNumber. The array of
winning numbers should be returned from a function called
getWinningNumbers. The display of the results should be done by a function
called displayResult(). The whole process should be kicked off by a function
called init. Thank you for your help!

Comment: How about you write the function and ask us for help if you run into trouble. We don't do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 x = checkNumber(12, 17, 24, 37, 38, 43);

 function checkNumber() {
   for (var i = 0; i < winningNumbers.length && !match ; i++)
  if (winningNumbers[i] == customerNumbers) {
  match = true; 
 }
}
```

} 
function getWinningNumbers

function displayResult(){

```
var message="This week Winning numbers are:" + "\n" + "\n" + winningNumbers + "\n" + "\n" + "The customer's Number is:" + "\n" + "\n" + customerNumbers + "\n" + "\n" + "We have a match and a winner!";
alert(message)
} Else
var message="This week Winning numbers are:" + "\n" + "\n" + winningNumbers + "\n" + "\n" + "The customer's Number is:" + "\n" + "\n" + customerNumbers + "\n" + "\n" + "Sorry you are not a winner this week";
alert(message)
}
```

}